# Embedded Resource missing in Visual Studio 2010 when name ends with "No.xxx"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, embedded-resource

I've come across a strange behaviour in Visual Studio 2010.

When using embedded resources (files which are added to my C# project and for which the *Build Action* property is set to `Embedded Resource`), the files are included in the output assembly as binary data. Listing the resources is straightforward:

```csharp
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] names = typeof (Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames ();

        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine (name);
        }
    }
}
```

However, if the embedded resource file name ends with `No.xxx` (the extension is irrelevant), the file does not show up in the list. I cannot figure out any reason why Visual Studio 2010 would not include such a file. What did I miss?

Note: if I rename the embedded resource file in the solution explorer to something else, then everything works as expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dan from the *Microsoft Connect* team has finally provided a [valid explanation](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/586804/embedded-resource-with-name-ending-in-no-xxx-will-not-be-included) for this behaviour:

> Hello, thanks for the report, this is actually working normally. The reason is that any resx files whose names match the pattern `.VALIDCULTURE.resx` are assumed to be specific to that culture. (This is how it has worked since VS2002, for better or worse)
> In your case `"no"` is a valid culture (*Norwegian*, I guess) so the build process builds it into a satellite assembly. Here's what I got when I tried this. Note the `"no"` subfolder. If in your app you change your current culture to Norwegian, the resource load will load this set of resources.

So the problem has nothing to do with the word `No` itself, but rather with the fact that it is a valid, two-letter, culture name (in my case Norwegian). I checked, and indeed, there was a sub-folder in `bin\Debug` named `No`, containing  a satellite assembly named `Project.resources.dll` in it.

Renaming the resource to end with `.EN.xxx` or `.FR.xxx` does, of course, exhibit the same behaviour.

---

As of **MSBuild 16.9** you can include files like these by setting the `WithCulture` property to `"false"`, as pointed out by @reduckted :-)

```xml
<EmbeddedResource Include="Resources.en.xml" WithCulture="false" />
```

Comment: As of MSBuild 16.9 you can include files like this by setting the `WithCulture` metadata to false like this: `<EmbeddedResource Include="Resources.en.xml" WithCulture="false" />`. See [this PR](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/pull/5824) for the implementation